# echo a sum then work it out

Tags: php, foreach, sum

In a table i have sums ie 1+1, im trying to make the code work the answer out and check it against the answer given by the end user.

Code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from exams where username = :username");
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => "$username"));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

$stmt->execute();
$question1 = $row['q1'];
foreach( $stmt as $row )
{

echo "q1<td>" . $row['q1'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['q1a'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>Correct = " . $question1 . "</td>";
}
```

Table information on the row q1

type = text

the varibles

```
$row['q1'] = 1+1
$row['q1a'] = there answer
$question1 = the right answer
```

i have tried  `$question1 = $row['q1'];`

and the output is always the sum in the table.

is there a way to echo the sum (in my table) out and find the value?

Comment: Please could you clarify, does $row['q1'] contain a string representing the question? i.e. "1+1" or "1+2". Also, is the question always an addition, or is it possible that its a subtraction etc..?

Comment: yes it does sorry i put it under varibles on my OP

Comment: Make sure you have a look at BC Math library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will not automatically work out the answer to the given question as this is currently stored as a string, you would first need to split the string into each individual part of the sum. You may wish to read more into the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Once the string is exploded into its parts (see example below) you can then add the two individual parts together to get the answer you were originally seeking:

```
$questionParts = explode('+',$row['q1']);
$answer = $questionParts[0] + $questionParts[1];
```